# How to detect a docker daemon port

Tags: docker

I have installed Ubuntu and Docker. I am trying to launch Raik container:

```
$ DOCKER_RIAK_AUTOMATIC_CLUSTERING=1 DOCKER_RAIK_CLUSTER_SIZE=5 DOCKER_RIAK_BACKEND=leveldb make start-cluster ./bin/start
```

and get the error message:

> It looks like the environment variable DOCKER_HOST has not been set. 
>   The Riak cluster cannot be started unless this has been set
>   appropriately.  For example:
>
> export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"

If I set

```
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://127.0.0.1:2375"
```

all my other containers stop working and said, that can not find the Docker daemon.

It looks like my Docker damon use other than 2375 port.  How can I check it ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

By default, the docker daemon will use the unix socket `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` (you can check this is the case for you by doing a `sudo netstat -tunlp` and note that there is no docker daemon process listening on any ports). It's recommended to keep this setting for security reasons but it sounds like Riak requires the daemon to be running on a TCP socket.

To start the docker daemon with a TCP socket that anybody can connect to, use the `-H` option:

```
sudo docker -H 0.0.0.0:2375 -d &
```

**Warning:** This means machines that can talk to the daemon through that TCP socket can get root access to your host machine.

Related docs:

http://basho.com/posts/technical/running-riak-in-docker/

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-where-the-docker-daemon-listens-for-connections

Comment: Actually, you might be able to get away with pointing it directly at the unix socket: `export DOCKER_HOST="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"`

Comment: That not the issue Chris, the installation of the riak container required a port binding.

Comment: hi @ChrisMcKinnel docker -H 0.0.0.0:2375 -d & gives me See 'docker --help'. I am usign docker 1.10. did they changed ?

Comment: Then you can use the daemon like so:  docker -H :2375  run -it [name]

Comment: This worked for me on 17.12

1)stop the service  -  sudo systemctl stop docker
2)Then,      sudo /usr/bin/dockerd -H 0.0.0.0:2375

Comment: How do we make this secure though?

Comment: as an additional note, `netstat -lnpx | grep docker.sock` should show you the socker file

Answer (score 57):

1. Prepare extra configuration file. Create a file named `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf`. Inside the file `docker.conf`, paste below content:

```conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

> Note that if there is no directory like `docker.service.d` or a file named `docker.conf` then you should create it.

2. Restart Docker. After saving this file, reload the configuration by  `systemctl daemon-reload` and restart Docker by `systemctl restart docker.service`.
3. Check your Docker daemon.  After restarting docker service, you can see the port in the output of  `systemctl status docker.service`
   like `/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

Hope this may help

Thank you!

Comment: Please be aware that anything that can access this port on the host now has remote root access. There's no encryption, no credentials, and it is actively scanned for on the internet.

Answer (score 20):

Reference docs of docker: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#configure-where-the-docker-daemon-listens-for-connections

There are **2 ways in configuring the docker daemon port**

1) Configuring at **/etc/default/docker** file:

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

2) Configuring at **/etc/docker/daemon.json**:

```
{
"debug": true,
"hosts": ["tcp://127.0.0.1:5000", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"]
}
```

If the docker default socket is not configured Docker will wait for infinite period.i.e

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
```

NOTE : **BUT DON'T CONFIGURE IN BOTH THE CONFIGURATION FILES**, the following error may occur :

```
Waiting for /var/run/docker.sock
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives are specified both as a flag and in the configuration file: hosts: (from flag: [tcp://127.0.0.1:5000 unix:///var/run/docker.sock], from file: tcp://127.0.0.1:5000)
```

The reason for adding both the **user port[ tcp://127.0.0.1:5000]** and **default docker socket[unix:///var/run/docker.sock]** is that the user port enables the access to the docker APIs whereas the default socket enables the CLI. In case the default port[unix:///var/run/docker.sock] is not mentioned in /etc/default/docker file the following error may occur:

```
# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

This error is not because that the docker is not running, but because of default docker socket is not enabled.

Once the configuration is enabled restart the docker service and verify the docker port is enabled or not:

```
# netstat -tunlp | grep -i 5000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31661/dockerd
```

Applicable for Docker Version 17.04, may vary with different versions of docker.

Comment: Can you include in your answer how to restart the Docker daemon service?

Comment: @PetrusTheron `systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 8):

Since I also had the same problem of "How to detect a docker daemon port" however I had on OSX and after little digging in I found the answer. I thought to share the answer here for people coming from osx.

If you visit [known-issues](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#known-issues) from docker for mac and [github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/770#issuecomment-252560286), you will find that by default the docker daemon only listens on unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock` and not on tcp. The default port for docker is [2375](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=2376) (unencrypted) and [2376](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?search=2376)(encrypted) communication over tcp(although you can choose any other port).

On OSX its not straight forward to run the daemon on tcp port. To do this one way is to use `socat` container to redirect the Docker API exposed on the unix domain socket to the host port on OSX.

```
docker run -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -p 127.0.0.1:2375:2375 bobrik/socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and then

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
```

However for local client on mac os you don't need to export DOCKER_HOST variable to test the api.

Comment: For newer versions, use the official socat from alpine. For more information https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/socat

Answer (score 3):

If you run `ps -aux | grep dockerd` you should see the endpoints it is running on.

Comment: i got `-H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`, so is that containerd the docker connection file?

Answer (score 1):

Try add `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`(at end of `Execstart` line) instead of `-H 0.0.0.0:2375`.